# Referencing CheckBoxes from last Activity giving me NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, checkbox, nullpointerexception

Is there a way to reference to an EditText/Checkbox from a previous XML file? On the final page of my app I want to capture some EditText and if any Checkboxes were checked on the previous page. I get a NullPointerException everytime I use the corresponding id because they aren't in the current XML files, but the previous one. Is there any way to reference these pieces and retrieve the info from the previous page? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Intent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) to pass data from one activity to another, you cannot directly access fields that are not there in your current view

```
Intent mIntent = new Intent(this, NewActivity.class);
mIntent .putExtra("CheckBox1", isChecked1);
mIntent .putExtra("CheckBox2", isChecked2);
mIntent .putExtra("stringRef", "Some more data");
startActivity(mIntent);
```

To recieve the values in new Activity.

```
    Intent intent = getIntent();
        if (intent != null) {
        String toGetSomeData = intent.getStringExtra("stringRef");
        boolean checkbox1 = intent.getBooleanExtra("CheckBox1", false); // false is default value
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Just to be clear the NewActivity.class would be whatever class I am currently trying to access them from. Got it. My only clarification is this code would go in the activity where the CheckBoxes are defined correct? Say PreviousActivity.class

Comment: Yes, you can find many examples online to pass data via Intent. This is most reliable method.

Comment: I am doing so now. The only question I have off the top of my head is do you have to specify which intent you are receiving? If you were sending more than one how do you know which one to take in? I'm sure I will come across it in my reading. Thank you for your help. You definitely gave me enough knowledge to learn and build off of from here.